# What are the possible sets of critical values of a complex polynomial of degree $n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Question: What are the possible sets of critical *values* of a degree $n \ge 2$ polynomial with complex coefficients? ($z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a critical value of $f$ if there is $w\in\mathbb{C}$ with $f(w)=z$ and $f'(w)=0$.)

The answer to this question is all sets of size $1$ to $n-1$, and I'm trying to prove it. I'm really just wondering what kind of techniques such a proof might involve (i.e. whether I can actually find a proof with my current knowledge). If anyone knows a proof and can give any small hint, that would be great.

Comment: When you say "critical values", you mean $f'(z)=0$?

Comment: @Chappers $w$ is a critical value of $f$ if there is a $z$ with $f(z) = w$ and $f'(z) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $n$.
If $n<1$ (i.e., $f$ is constant), then all points are critical, but all lead to the same critical value. In this case we have $1>n$ critical values, contrary to your claim.

Next let $f$ be linear (i.e., $n=1$). Then $f'$ has no root hence there is no critical value, again contrary to your claim.

Assume henceforth that $n\ge 2$.
Then $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$, hence has at least one root in $\mathbb C$ and consequently there is at least one critical value.
Also, the number of distinct roots of $f'$ is at most $\deg f'=n-1$ (here we use that $n-1>0$). Hence the number of critical values is also at most $n-1$.
And indeed, any set of $1$ up to $n-1$ can occur as number of critical points, as can be shown by exhibiting suitable  example polynomials:
[Hold on, at this point there's still something gappy]

Comment: I can show that there's a degree $n$ polynomial with $k$ distinct critical points for $1\le k \le n-1$, but I want to show that I can also control what the critical values are.

Comment: It seems like we may have different definitions of *critical value*. I've added my definition into the question to clarify things.